# Change the status of dokan plugin

Tags: dokan

Hello thank you for helping me
I want to change the product status of the product in the dokan plugin after it has been edited, which is still published? please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to `admin panel` > `dokan` > `settings` > `selling options` and check the option `Edited Product Status`. See following image
[image: Screen sort]